# What is 0.25801227546?

Tags: approximation

Due to specific knowledge, I know that this is a constant which has a very nice closed form expression (probably short and in terms of square roots, rationals, and $\pi$). However, the Inverse Symbolic Calculator and I can't find it. What is $0.25801227546$ a very good approximation to?

Comment: Can you give any further context on this 'specific knowledge'?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha thinks that it could be an approximation of $8/\pi^3$.

Comment: @orlp It was the value of a summation that is supposed to telescope. I haven't made it telescope yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the program [$\texttt{ries}$](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html) and it found a close match:

```
> ries 0.25801227546

   Your target value: T = 0.25801227546                          mrob.com/ries

               cospi(x) = ln(2)                  for x = T - 0.00178869  {54}
                e^(1/x) = 7^2                    for x = T - 0.0010631   {62}
                   3"/x = 2/pi                   for x = T + 5.59597e-12 {69}
                  (for more results, use the option '-l3')

  ln(x) = natural logarithm or log base e  cospi(X) = cos(pi * x)
  A"/B = Ath root of B  pi = 3.14159...
```

which gives the value $(2/\pi)^3$.